# composing function adding new parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, functional-programming

I'm currently learning JavaScript and got stuck by adding a parameter to my function that should add two numbers.
I'm not new to programming. 
Did a lot in Java and C#, but Javascript drives me crazy with scope and compose and currying....
So here is my problem:

```
const compose = (f, g) => (a) => f(g(a));
const add1 = (num) => num + 1;
const add5 = (num) => num + 5;
compose(add1, add5)(10)          // 16
```

The code above works!
But i want that the +1 and +5 number to be variable so that i can have like this:

```
// Something linke this 
const compose = (f, g) => (a,b) => f(g(a,b));
const add1 = (num, num2) => num + num2;
const add5 = (num, num2) => num + num2;
compose(add1, add5)(10, 4)   // Those numbers should be the Parameter input for add1 and add5 (num, num2)
```

Comment: You seem to be making this very complicated, what's wrong with just creating a `function compose(){...}`? No one gives extra marks for making things complicated

Comment: What would you expect to be returned here? Both functions expect two arguments, if you want to pass same numbers to both functions, how do you compose those?

Comment: @Liam - This sort of exercises are quite valuable for deep understanding of the language. Obviously, those should not be used i  production unless really required.

Comment: In `f(g(a, b))`, `g(a, b)` is 1st parameter and 2nd parameter is missing

Comment: I am not trying to make things complicated, i just want to really really understand how to add a parameter to my compose method and make it variable and not hardcoding some numbers.

Comment: Expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
    const addN = (n) => num => num + n
    const compose = (f,g) => a => f(g(a));
    const result = compose(addN(10),addN(4))(1);
    console.log(result);
```

`addN` creates adder functions, in this case an `add10` and an `add4`. Instead of returning a value as your original `add1` and `add5` did, `addN` is returning a function *like* `add1` and `add5` except it isn't hardcoded to be +1 or +5; it is + whatever you passed in when you called `addN`.

```
console.log(addN(6)(10)); //16
```

`addN(6)` creates an "add6" function, and then we call that "add6" function with 10 to get the output of 16

Comment: @ Anthony  thank youuuuuuuuuu!
That's it.
Could you please explain it a liitle ?

Comment: @Codex0607 I put a little more in, hopefully that helps!

Comment: glad there are such community like Stackoverflow !!!!
Thank you all guys !
Sorry Anthony, i cant give you a upvote, cuz i'm a new user.
again thanks!!!!!!!
Edit: Now i got my Upvotes priviliges and you got one from me!
BTW....your explanation is very newbie friendly

Answer (score 0):

You can also use curried function like this to achieve the same in a better / simpler way without composing it.

```
// add = a => b => Number
const add = a => b => a + b;

const result = add(2)(3); // => 5
```

First, the function takes a, and then returns a new function, which then takes b returns the sum of a and b. Each argument is taken one at a time. If the function had more parameters, it could simply continue to return new functions until all of the arguments are supplied and the application can be completed.